# Drush folder after installation?

Tags: drupal

I installed Drush with `apt-get install drush`. `which drush` says the file has been installed on /usr/bin/drush.

I would like to manually update Drush as well as adding files like an example.alias.php file to that folder. However, /user/bin/drush isn't actually a folder but the PHP file itself.

How can I find the Drush folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is installed here: `/usr/share/drush`